# iFrame jQuery calling jQuery Function in parent

Tags: jquery, function, iframe

- How do I get jQuery in an iFrame to call a jQuery function in the parent?

**Here is code for iFrame**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $("#Hey").click(function ()
        {

            parent.WorkPlease(); // does not work
                   window.parent.WorkPlease(); // also does not work
                   // Both hosted on same domain

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is the jQuery on the parent page hosting the iFrame**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    function WorkPlease()
    {
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#iFrame").offset().top}, 5000);// 
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the parent's DOM from the `iframe`, but within the same domain. This seems to be your case.

The problem with your code is that the `workPlease` function is defined as a local variable of the anonymous function you pass to the `document` `ready` event handler, and not in the `window` object of the parent page itself.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.workPlease = function()
    {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#iFrame").offset().top}, 5000);// 
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I AM able control another div in the parent from jQuery in an iFrame. Is that not accessing external content?

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
  
        $("#Hey").click(function (){
            //$(this).animate(function(){
                window.parent.$(".Main").animate({ 
        
       height:"300px"
    
      }, 1500 );
            //});
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: You are right. You should be able to access the parent window object from within the same domain. I reviewed your code and found the issue was somewhere else.

Comment: That's it! You got it Bro. Thanks my friend.